# How to focus a JSF component based on a condition?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem executing a specific script, the focus one:

```
PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("document.getElementById(\"myPage:myElement\").focus();")
```

The problem is that it didn't execute. I know the problem is not with PrimeFaces, because if I try to execute a script of an alert it works. Also the id is correct, I checked multiple times.

The element I'm trying to focus is p:inputTextbut, from the front-end it works (if I had to do it on the frontend I have to change all the logic).

Do someone know why it's not working? Maybe it can't be done on java part?

Comment: Why aren't you using the `p:focus` tag? https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/focus.xhtml

Comment: I have a p:focus tag, is setted for="firstElement".

Comment: The problem is that I need to change the focus in a specific condition.

Comment: Try `<p:focus for="#{condition ? elementA : elementB}"/>`

Comment: That should work, but then I will need the return value of the java function.

Maybe the code should be rewrite in js..

Comment: Depends on the condition. Anyhow, currently your question is not really answerable. I'm just throwing suggestions at you ;-)

Comment: I finally resolved it basically with a porkaround. It works, but I'm ashamed of what I've done so I won't tell my solution.

Comment: No reason to be ashamed. You could post your solution as an answers and might receive some tips to improve it.